# Implementing MVP with Dagger in a FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, mvp, fragmentpageradapter

I'm trying to set up a tabbed layout with MVP and having some difficulties. I'm using [Google's Dagger MVP sample app](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp-dagger/) as a general reference, and they store the reference to the each presenter in each activity. However, in my tabbed layout, I'm using one activity with a fragment for each tab (delivered via a FragmentPagerAdapter). The fragments are instantiated and their presenters injected in the FragmentPagerAdapter's getItem() method. The problem is, when the app is rotated, my fragments get rebuilt automatically but don't get their presenters back and then crash due to an NPE. I've been storing the presenters as fields in either the activity or the FragmentPagerAdapter (a la Google) but neither work and that seems hacky anyway.

This is basically how I do it in the FragmentPagerAdapter now:

```
public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    @Inject MyPresenter mMyPresenter;

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem (int position){
    switch (position) {
        case MY_FRAGMENT_INDEX:
            return createMyFragment;
        case OTHER_FRAGMENT_INDEX:
            return createMyOtherFragment;
        default:
            return null;
    }

    private Fragment createMyFragment() {
        MyFragment myFragment = MyFragment.newInstance();
        // make the presenter
        DaggerMyPresenterComponent.builder()
                .MyModelComponent(
                        ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getMyModelComponent())
                .MyPresenterModule(new MyPresenterModule(myFragment)).build()
                .inject(this);
        return myFragment;
    }
```

What's a good architecture to approach this sort of situation? Where should I keep references to the presenters (if at all), and how do I manage their instantiation and re-creation (if the FragmentPagerAdapter won't do it for me)?

Comment: Did you ever find a nice way of doing this?